# How environment variables are used when deployed on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

I am building a web application that utilises environment variables locally, and I want to put this on production (online). I am trying to find out how to set environment variables on AWS.

This is a node.js application and I am using elastic beanstalk on AWS for deployment. I have looked through https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/env-vars.html#env-vars-env-list , but I'm unsure of which option applies to me.

The .env file I have locally contains lines like

PASSWORD=MYPASSWORD

and I am using the dotenv package, with require('dotenv').config(); in the appropriate files. I am accessing environment variables in my code through things like process.env.PASSWORD (using the aforementioned example of a line in the .env file).

I've tried searching several places and am presented with various options, but I'm not sure which one applies to my environment variables.

Comment: Have you tried process.env.VARNAME ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you are following may help you in ec2 machine that is mangages by you, but if you are working Elasticbeanstalk I will recommend using [**Environment variable configuration provided by elasticbeanstalk**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html).

I am not in favour of `.env` in case of Elasticbeanstalk, ECS and many other services where AWS provide easy and out of the box feature to set environment variable in the configuration and `.env` write environment to file which is less secure then system environment variable.

The interesting part of Elasticbeanstalk ENV is, the system environment variable has higher periphery then `.env` environment variable but better to not place dotenv on elasticbeanstalk.

**Environment Properties and Other Software Settings**

> You can use environment properties to pass secrets, endpoints, debug
>   settings, and other information to your application. Environment
>   properties help you run your application in multiple environments for
>   different purposes, such as development, testing, staging, and
>   production.

[elasticbeanstalk-deploy_nodejs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html)

```
Example .ebextensions/options.config

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    API_ENDPOINT: www.example.com/api
```

Now all you need

```
var endpoint = process.env.API_ENDPOINT
```

**Environment Properties**

> The Environment Properties section lets you specify environment
>   configuration settings on the Amazon EC2 instances that are running
>   your application. These settings are passed in as key-value pairs to
>   the application.
>
> Inside the Node.js environment running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, you
>   can access the environment variables using `process.env.ENV_VARIABLE`
>   similar to the following example.

```
var endpoint = process.env.API_ENDPOINT
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped - it's worth pointing out that using require dotenv in your code will cause the health to degrade and your app won't work (at least that's what I found).