# AWS EB not using Environment Variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables

I have deployed a Next JS app to my AWS EB instance and it is still using my env.local variables from my dist folder I uploaded. I would like the uploaded version to use the variables I have set up in Configuration > Software. Do I need to do anything to get it to use these instead?
I was under the impression it used these by default? Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was answered here

[How environment variables are used when deployed on aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557951/how-environment-variables-are-used-when-deployed-on-aws)

In short: do not put .env files when you deploy on beanstalk. furthermore, env.local should be in your .gitignore list, as recommended here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables